# Why was the man from seat 61 put on hold?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I made a question here: [How up to date is the Man from seat 61?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49851/how-reliable-is-the-man-from-seat-61)

For some reason the question was put on hold. I can even understand that at a first glance the question might considered too broad. But I got some really good answers telling about the update rate of the website and explaining how the update process works including the time-stamp information.

When this happens why do people insist in considering the questions too broad?

In general, in this situations some time should be given to a question. I think the answers will prove (or not) if a question is too broad or not.

Answer (score 7):

I voted to reopen. For starters the question isn't broad. It might be opinion-based since the answers would rely on anecdotes by people who actually used the website and found it reliable/not reliable. However we received an answer by the *man* himself, explaining how he goes about to keep up the reliability by updating the site on a constant basis.

What can be done to improve the on-topicness of the question it to reword it to something like: `How up to date is the Man in Seat61?`, to better fit the accepted answer.

Comment: +1, I voted to close because the question as stated was essentially opinion-based. "How reliable" is inherent subjective; we can't say "Seat61.com scores somewhere between 650 and 720 reliability units (0.65-0.72 kilorels, or 26-28 BRUs in the US)." Many, perhaps most *how* questions are problematic in the same way— how easy, how comfortable, how busy, how careful: rarely is a frame of reference provided. *How up to date?* is a big improvement, because it can be answered without resorting to anecdote or conjecture into the questioner's standards.

Comment: Theoretically you can measure "how reliable". Take all information from the site, check if they are correct and then you can make a statement like: 75% reliable.

Comment: You'd need a statistical tests with a 95% reliability to be precise. 75% is unreliable. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO That's also subjective. :)

Comment: @reirab Maybe so. But repeatable. :)

Comment: I believe the proper answer is "yes".

Answer (score 4):

After 2 reopen votes, I cast another reopen vote and the question is now reopened. As @JoErNanO already mentioned, the question is not too broad. It is quite specific and definitively also not off-topic. Concerning the opinion-based problem. The question might elicit a lot of opinions or anecdotal evidences, but it would (at least theoretically) also be possible to evaluate the reliability objectively.